# How to completely block ssh and pings to server running Oracle Linux 6.7

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

We are facing IP abuse issues and want to completely **BLOCK** *ssh* and ability to *ping* our servers running [Oracle Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux) 6.7 and only allow vnc connections. How to achieve this using linux firewall or iptables?

Comment: I would avise allowing ssh over VPN and especially vnc. As for ping, if you are disabling only reply and requests, you might as well disable it in the kernel.

Comment: `ufw`, is a front end to iptable, it makes it easier, it also does ip6tables. `gufw` is a graphical front end for `ufw`.

Comment: To block ssh, why don't you simply uninstall `sshd`?

Answer (score 5):

As OEL 6 using iptables;

Allow ICMP traffic to leave your server, ie so you can ping out

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Then block IMCP replies:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP
$ iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

SSH would be the same, assuming SSH is on port 22.

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

but you could allow SSH from a single IP, or range;

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

(Note the use of `-I` to insert the rule at the start of the `ACCEPT` chain instead of using `-A` which would place it after the `DROP` rule and negate its effect.)

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly and blocked all ssh connections, but the IPs I am trying to allow are not working. Allowed IPs only in same subnet are able to ssh connect.